# Method template - multiplie definition - what I'm doing wrrong?

Tags: c++, c++14, linker-errors

I'm new in c++ and I have problem with templating method in class.

[cutted]

--- full code after suggestions ---

**serializerService.h**

```
// Copyright (c) 2019 All rights reserved.
//
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "ThorSerialize/SerUtil.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"

class SerializerService {
public:

    template <class T>
    std::string serialize(T &entity){
        using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExport;
        using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::PrinterInterface;

        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << jsonExport(entity, PrinterInterface::OutputType::Stream);
        return stream.str();
    };
};
```

**serializerService.cpp**

```
//#include "serializerService.h"
```

and **mainEndpoint.cpp** where `serializerService.h` is included also

```
#include <user.h>
#include "serializerService.h"
#include "mainEndpoint.h"

void MainEndpoint::doMain(const Pistache::Rest::Request &request, Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter response) {

    User user("admin@admin.com");
    user.setUsername("admin");

    SerializerService serializer;

    std::string data = serializer.serialize(user);


    response.cookies()
            .add(Pistache::Http::Cookie("lang", "pl_PL"));
    response.headers()
            .add<Pistache::Http::Header::Server>("Sandbox server v0.1")
            .add<Pistache::Http::Header::ContentType>(MIME(Application, Json));
//    response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, "{}");
    response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, data);
}
```

When I enable in `serializerService.cpp` line including header file I got errors:

```
====================[ Build | sandbox | Debug ]=================================
/home/marcin/Programs/clion-2019.1.3/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/cmake-build-debug --target sandbox -- -j 8
[ 76%] Built target pistache
[ 80%] Linking CXX executable sandbox
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreValue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:6: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreValue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:6: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheValue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:47: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheValue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:47: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheMap()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:15: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheMap()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:15: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheArray()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:27: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreTheArray()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:27: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::JsonManualLexer(std::istream&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:10: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::JsonManualLexer(std::istream&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:10: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::JsonManualLexer(std::istream&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:10: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::JsonManualLexer(std::istream&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:10: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::yylex()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:16: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::yylex()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:16: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readTrue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:65: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readTrue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:65: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readFalse()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:70: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readFalse()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:70: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readNull()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:75: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readNull()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:75: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readNumber(int)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:182: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readNumber(int)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:182: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::checkFixed(char const*, unsigned long)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:240: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::checkFixed(char const*, unsigned long)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:240: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::ignoreRawValue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:80: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::ignoreRawValue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:80: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::error()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:251: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::error()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:251: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getRawString[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:98: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getRawString[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:98: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getString[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:147: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getString[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:147: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getLastBool() const':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:152: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::getLastBool() const'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:152: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::isLastNull() const':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:164: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::isLastNull() const'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:164: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readDigits(char)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:169: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonManualLexer::readDigits(char)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonManualLexer.source:169: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::JsonParser(std::istream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ParserConfig)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:12: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::JsonParser(std::istream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ParserConfig)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:12: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::JsonParser(std::istream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ParserConfig)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:12: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::JsonParser(std::istream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ParserConfig)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:12: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getNextToken()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:21: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getNextToken()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:21: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getString[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:139: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getString[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:139: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getRawString[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:143: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getRawString[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:143: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::ignoreDataValue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:147: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::ignoreDataValue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:147: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getKey[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:152: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getKey[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:152: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(short&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:162: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(short&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:162: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(int&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:163: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(int&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:163: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:164: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:164: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long long&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:165: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long long&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:165: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned short&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:167: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned short&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:167: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned int&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:168: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned int&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:168: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:169: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:169: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long long&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:170: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(unsigned long long&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:170: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(float&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:172: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(float&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:172: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(double&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:173: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(double&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:173: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long double&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:174: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(long double&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:174: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(bool&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:177: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(bool&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:177: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:182: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:182: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::isValueNull()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:187: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::isValueNull()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:187: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getRawValue[abi:cxx11]()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:192: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonParser::getRawValue[abi:cxx11]()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonParser.source:192: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::JsonPrinter(std::ostream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::PrinterInterface::PrinterConfig)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:112: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::JsonPrinter(std::ostream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::PrinterInterface::PrinterConfig)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:112: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::JsonPrinter(std::ostream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::PrinterInterface::PrinterConfig)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:112: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::JsonPrinter(std::ostream&, ThorsAnvil::Serialize::PrinterInterface::PrinterConfig)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:112: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openDoc()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:119: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openDoc()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:119: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeDoc()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:121: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeDoc()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:121: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openMap()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:124: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openMap()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:124: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeMap()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:129: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeMap()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:129: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openArray(unsigned long)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:138: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::openArray(unsigned long)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:138: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeArray()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:143: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::closeArray()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:143: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addKey(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:153: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addKey(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:153: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addValue(short)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:179: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addValue(short)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:179: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addValue(int)':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:180: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::JsonPrinter::addValue(int)'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/JsonPrinter.source:180: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(sandbox)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage")

add_subdirectory(lib/pistache)

include_directories(include lib/odb/libodb lib/odb/libodb-pgsql lib/ThorsSerializer)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/sandbox.cpp
src/Security/authSecurity.cpp src/Entity/user.cpp
src/Service/serializerService.cpp
src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp
)


add_executable(sandbox ${SOURCE_FILES})
#add_library()

set(ODB_LIBRARIES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/odb/libodb/odb/.libs/libodb.a
        )

target_link_libraries(sandbox pistache pthread ${ODB_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Move the implementation into the `.hpp` file.

Comment: ok, I moved implementation to .h file but I got many errors with multideclarations so I had to comment `//#include "serializerService.h"` in .cpp file.

Comment: If you moved the implementation to `serializerService.h`, you shouldn't have any left in the `.cpp` file that could be in conflict with what you have in `serializerService.h`.  Do you have an include guard in `serializerService.h`? You don't show any in the code above.

Comment: Yes, I moved full implementation to `.h` file and `.cpp` file is empty. In header file as first line I have `#pragma once` so should be guarded. This header file is used in `mainEndpoint.cpp` also because I use typo. And then when I put `#include "serializerService.h"` in `serializerService.cpp` then I have errors with _multiple definition_. I don't know why this happens :/

Comment: I pasted full code above

Comment: You should be able to include `serializerService.h` in all the `.cpp` and `.h` files you want. Do you get the same errors if you compile one `.cpp` file at a time into object files manually and then try linking the object files into a program? What is your current error? Btw, "_Copyright (c) 2019 All rights reserved._" and posting the code here isn't a good idea.

Comment: I didn't try to link manually. This CLion with CMake does.

Comment: current error:`[ 84%] Linking CXX executable sandbox
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o: in function `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreValue()':
/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:6: multiple definition of `ThorsAnvil::Serialize::ParserInterface::ignoreValue()'; CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Endpoint/mainEndpoint.cpp.o:/home/marcin/CLionProjects/sandbox/lib/ThorsSerializer/ThorSerialize/Serialize.source:6: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp`

Comment: My question was more of a suggestion. :-) Try to compile each `.cpp` manually into object files. Then link them. Your CMake project may be setup incorrectly. Why is `serializerService.cpp.o` showing up? Remove `serializerService.cpp` from the project since it's empty.

Comment: I can include any header file anywhere, only when I'm including `serializerService.h` twice i have the multiple definition errors

Comment: Try a standard include guard. `#pragma once` isn't standard (yet). Did you try to compile the `.cpp` files manually and then link them? Remove `CMakeFiles/sandbox.dir/src/Service/serializerService.cpp.o` before you compile and remove `serializerService.cpp` completely. Can you then include `serializerService.h` in many other `.h` and `.cpp` files?

Comment: problem is with ThorSerialize included headers. I changed my method to return pure string to disable serializer headers and everythin is compiled well. I can include `serializerService.h` in many files.

Comment: Ok, author of ThorsSerializer fixed the bug and now everything works well.

Comment: Brilliant! Your helped making the library better!